# Is there a way to automatically activate a script when a USB device connects?

Tags: usb, script, data-transfer

I have a USB device (POV camera) that collects a lot of data a fills up its storage regularly. The goal is to write a script that:

1. Listens for the device to connect via USB
2. Mounts it as a storage device
3. Downloads data from the device
4. Safely unmounts the device for removal (upon completion of the download)

I can add to the script later the option for blinking LEDs attached to certain pins on the GPIO to indicate status...

I've searched for "how to automatically download data from a usb device" on ubuntu and other linux sites, but with no results. Can anyone provide a starting point? I'm comfortable with writing code from documentation and examples.

Answer (score 13):

Use **udev** rules.

find your device information.

```
udevadm -a -p /dev/path/device/

KERNELS=="1-3"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
...
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="SANDisk"
ATTRS{product}=="USB DISK"
ATTRS{serial}=="SD71011000019113"
```

Then create your udev rules file for your device. When creating rules file, use information you got from udevinfo command.

content of **/etc/udev/rules.d/99-mydevice.rules**

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="SD71011000019113", RUN+="/home/gurcan/sync.sh"
```

Create your script that will run as USB device connected

```
#!/bin/bash
#
rsync -avz /media/disk/photos/ /data/photos/
```

Reload udev rules

```
udevcontrol reload_rules
```

Test it. unplug/plug

Comment: I tried to run udevinfo, but got a `-bash: udevinfo: command not found` response from the ssh shell. I checked `man` and there is a `man` entry for `udev`, but not for `udevinfo`. I will likely try to pursue this with `udev`... your answer was helpful though, so thanks! I'll look around to check on `udevinfo` too, maybe I haven't installed a repository or something.

Comment: @user3.1415927 Because of udevinfo replaced by udevadm in debian, i updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like udev, you can take a look on [devmon](http://igurublog.wordpress.com/downloads/script-devmon/).

It allows these options:

`--exec-on-device DEVICE "COMMAND"  Execute COMMAND after mounting DEVICE
--exec-on-label "LABEL" "COMMAND"  Execute COMMAND after mounting LABEL
--exec-on-video "COMMAND"          Execute COMMAND after video DVD mount
--exec-on-audio "COMMAND"          Execute COMMAND after audio CD insertion
--exec-on-disc  "COMMAND"          Execute COMMAND after data CD/DVD mount
--exec-on-drive "COMMAND"          Execute COMMAND after drive mount
--exec-on-unmount "COMMAND"        Execute COMMAND after unmount
--exec-on-remove  "COMMAND"        Execute COMMAND after drive removal
  Where the following in COMMAND will be replaced with:
     %d    mount point directory (eg /media/cd)
     %f    device name (eg /dev/sdd1)
     %l    label of mounted volume
  Multiple --exec-on-XXX options may be used to execute multiple commands.
  Other exec-on-XXX commands are ignored if exec-on-device or -label executed.`