# How can i automatically USB mount and run a shell script?

Tags: usb, mount, script

I have a USB device (Pen drive) that collects a lot of data a fills up its storage regularly. The goal is to write a script that:

- accesses USB device
- mounts it as a storage device
- downloads data from the device
- safely unmounts the device for removal (upon completion of the download)

I found this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19600/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-activate-a-script-when-a-usb-device-connects).

I have done all things from this but my udev rules are not reflected.
The shell script which I have set in `.rules` file is not running on USB mount. My rules file is `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-mydevice.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="sd*",SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}="1d6b",ATTR{idProduct}="0002",ATTR{serial}="3f980000.usb",RUN+="/home/pi/newfile.sh"
```

and my USB system path is `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it works for me:

## cat /etc/udev/rules.d/11-media-by-label-with-pmount.rules

KERNEL!="sd[a-z]*", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
ACTION=="add", PROGRAM!="/sbin/blkid %N", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid -o value -s LABEL %N", ENV{dir_name}="%c"

PROGRAM=="/usr/bin/basename '%E{dir_name}'", ENV{dir_name}="%c"
ENV{dir_name}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

ACTION=="add", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/su JrtFlash-c '/usr/bin/pmount %N %E{dir_name}'", RUN+="/home/pi/my-script.sh"
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/su JrtFlash-c '/usr/bin/pumount /media/%E{dir_name}'"
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

and tested using command:

## udevadm test $(udevadm info -q sys-path) 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

Udev statements containing a single `=` are assignments, not comparisons. For example `ATTR{idVendor}="1d6b"` tries to assign a newly plugged USB device a particular Vendor ID, and failing since Vendor IDs are read only. You want to use `==` in comparisons.

Comment: I tried this too but its not working.
My script is as follows:

#!/bin/bash
cp /media/pi/dev_name/test.txt /home/pi/newfile.txt
echo File transfer > log.txt

Once USB inserted cant get any logs in log.txt.

Plz help on this.