# Is there a way to automatically activate a script when g_mass_storage reads or writes

Tags: raspbian-stretch, systemd

I'm using the g_mass_storage on the raspberry pi. Is there any way to trigger a script when the host writes to the pi?

Everywhere I've looked has talked about using triggers based upon [usb mounting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19600/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-activate-a-script-when-a-usb-device-connects)

Comment: `host writes to the pi`??? ... more info, please

Comment: @jsotola look up `g_mass_storage` and you'll know what he's talking about.